# segregating duplicates in excel column

Tags: excel, vba

There were options to highlight/delete the duplicate data in a column (excel 2010) but I need those duplicate data to be displayed in another column.
Let us consider column A has 500 data in which 15 were duplicate, I need the 15 to be displayed in column C for easy viewing. (Need a macro)

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you have a look at the wealth of answers to very similar questions here?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub DuplicatesList()
    Dim A As Range, r As Range, i As Long
    Set A = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
    Dim c As Collection, v As String
    Set c = New Collection
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In A
        v = r.Text
        If v <> "" Then
            If wf.CountIf(A, v) > 1 Then
                c.Add v, CStr(v)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    On Error GoTo 0

    If c.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        Cells(i, "B").Value = c.Item(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Here is sample input and output:

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you. Could you please add description for the code lines (using ') so if any small change is required I can do that. Also from your example ralph is repeated twice but in result only once it shows up. I need all duplictes for n number of times to be displayed. Thanks in advance.